# String Pathing BFS

Tags: java, string, path, breadth-first-search

I am trying to find the shortest path between two strings, and return an int of how many steps were taken. Given that I have a HashMap in which each String(key) has a `String[]`(object) containing all of that strings neighbours.

This code is what I whipped up. I just took a basic BFS and tried to copy that, but I can't quite figure out a way to progress.

```
public class Main {
private static HashMap<String, String[]> list;

private static int makePath(String from, string to) {

    int path = 0;
    PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    queue.add(from);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        String u = queue.poll();
        if (u == to) {
            return path;
        }
        else {
            for (String r : list.get(u)) {

               ...

            }
            return path;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

}
```

This is just an example of what my HashMap might look like:

```
Goat, adj[] {Fish, Cow, Chicken}
Cow, adj[] {Pig, Pigeon}
Fish, adj[] {Goat, Bulbasaur, Dolphin, Eagle}
```

From Fish to Cow I need two steps. From Fish to Goat and Goat to Fish.

So if you got any ideas feel free to share :)

Comment: What do you mean by "string path"?  Do you mean something like the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: The path there is between two strings in a set. Where each string has an array of it's neighbours - contained in a HashMap.

Comment: I think he is trying to say that he has a graph data structure, and is looking for some shortest path algorithm between nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking of using 2 Queues. I will enqueue the `from` word to the firstQueue, and while `firstQueue` is not empty, I will perform an alternating logic to store the neighbors in the other queue if that neighbor is still not equal to `to`.

It'll be clearer if I give the code,

```
private static int makePath(final HashMap<String, String[]> tree, final String from, final String to) {

        int path = 0;
        Queue<String> firstQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Queue<String> secondQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        firstQueue.add(from);

        while (!firstQueue.isEmpty()) {
            String key = firstQueue.poll();
            String[] neighbors = tree.get(key);
            if (neighbors != null) {
                path++;
                for (String neighbor : neighbors) {
                    if (neighbor.equals(to)) {
                        return path;
                    } else {
                        secondQueue.add(neighbor);
                    }
                }
            }

            while (!secondQueue.isEmpty()) {
                key = secondQueue.poll();
                neighbors = tree.get(key);
                if (neighbors != null) {
                    path++;
                    for (String neighbor : neighbors) {
                        if (neighbor.equals(to)) {
                            return path;
                        } else {
                            firstQueue.add(neighbor);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
```